# get information about a view that just created

Tags: android, android-layout

First , hello.
I have a preblem - i want to get the top in pixel of my view that just created from xml file.
there is the on create method. i need to get information about the layout but, the layout hasn't created yet. So what to do>>?! i tried to use the OnStart and the OnResume method but the layout isn't created even then.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //full screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    //full screen
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setIdAndConsturtor();
    buildLevels();
    setIdViews();
    setEvents();



}
```

Comment: Have you tried inflating the view executing the methods and after all calling setContentView? (I'm guessing you know how to do that).

Comment: YESS!, in the setIdViews() method i tried, but it returns me a zero when i call the method myview.getBottom() (and the bottom isn;t zero) so  I assumed that the view hasn't created YET!!

Comment: Could you post this method? The one you call getBottom()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the methods inside this one:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    //Here you can get put the methods
    setIdAndConsturtor();
    buildLevels();
    setIdViews();
    setEvents();
}
```